# Should I really be using PDO and prepared statements?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

PDO and prepared statements are still kind of confusing to me, no matter how much I read about them so far.  So I know they are more "secure" but is it really that important?  I mean I can get the same end result using basic mysql with mysql_real_escape_string() and  htmlspecialchars() right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could, but PDO and prepared statements are the absolute safest. Could you do it by hand and use the `mysql_real_escape_string()` function? Sure. In fact, your output might look identical. But in the end, the code that PDO would require would be a hell of a lot shorter than the code if you had done it manually.

Also, if you aren't using prepared statements, you run the risk of human error: say you forget to escape a value or sanitize an input. Mixed in with all of your other code, the one line that isn't properly sanitizing could crop up to be a nightmare down the road.

Hope this helps!

Comment: "prepared statements are the absolute safest", "your output might look identical" - What? Why?! Prepared statements are as secure as using `mysql_real_escape_string()` and the output will always look identical.

Comment: Alix: There's less of a chance for human error. If you always escape everything properly (i.e.: PDO) because the only way you're loading data into a query is via an escaping function, then you're guaranteed that the data is 100% sanitary.

And no, the output will not always look identical. Quoting styles, escaping styles, and support for data types will vary depending on which approach you take.

Answer (score 3):

I really like the PDO interface. Once you get used to it, it's a lot cleaner than the mysql_* function style.  It took me a while to figure it out, too, but it's worth it.

The part that I found confusing was remembering what methods belong to the PDO DB connection object itself, and which are part of the statement objects.

With certain actions, you'll get a performance benefit from repeating prepared statements, too. For instance, if you're doing a bunch of inserts in a loop, you can prepare the statement, and then bind new data in the loop each time before inserting.

The security is much better too, in that you are relying on a well tested library to escape your data on each insert. It's like cryptography - why do it yourself, when it's something this important? There's no reason to give yourself a chance to get it wrong (i.e., accidentally miss escaping something inserted into a query).

I recommend [this guide](http://www.kitebird.com/articles/php-pdo.html) to PDO, from the author who wrote this [excellent giant book on Mysql](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672329387).

I like to use the positional parameter style, and then you just make an array of the data and pass it in. My queries look like

```
$pdo_db=pdo_connect('cow_db');
$sql='select this,that,count(those) as snout from lovely_table where name=? and horses=?';
$data=array($username,$horse_count);

$query_stmt=$pdo_db->prepare($sql);
$result_handle=$query_stmt->execute($data);

//then I have a function to load data from the result handle
$info=load_array($result_handle);
```

You could make functions like this to work with the standard php mysql interface, but why not just use PDO?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with others who say using prepared queries is generally better than using escaping functions.  It's easier to use correctly, and there's no way that parameter values can introduce SQL injection problems, since the value are sent to the RDBMS server separately from the SQL query.

However, using parameters is useful only when the dynamic parts of your SQL query is a parameter in lieu of a literal value in an expression.  You can't use a query parameter in place of a table name, column name, an SQL expression, or a list of values (e.g. arguments of an `IN( )` predicate).

Prepared queries also have **better performance** than non-prepared queries (at least in MySQL).  Most people say the opposite, but the well-respected mysqlperformanceblog.com did the testing:

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/08/02/mysql-prepared-statements/

Answer (score 0):

As long as you sanitize data appropriately for your queries then you don't **have** to use PDO/prepared statements. *Though*, I would personally recommend using PDO/prepared statements simply because they do both make development/debugging easier and prepared statements prevent incorrect data types from even getting in to a query.

If you want to learn more about how to create a simple prepared statement look in to the function `sprintf`. You simply replace any variable strings, integers, etc with a type specifier (in this case `%s` and `%d` respectively).

So for example in the following query, I know that `id` is going to be an integer (it will be numerical) and `name` will be a string (alphanumeric).

```
$username = 'Simon';
$id       = 3;
$query    = "SELECT FROM `users` WHERE `id` = {$id} AND `name` = '{$username}'";
```

If I'm getting either of this variables from an un-trusted source (such as a POST/GET) then I can make sure they are the correct data types by replacing the final line (the $query set) with a `sprintf` call like this:

```
$username = 'Simon';
$id       = 3;
$query    = sprintf( "SELECT FROM `users` WHERE `id` = %d AND `name` = '%s'", $id, $username );
```

`sprintf` will simply not let me use a string for the $id or an integer for the $name when it is called which ensures the correct types of data are given (this gives me that little extra bit of security). IF incorrect data types ARE given then *I believe* it'll cast the variables to the requested type.

To read more about `sprintf` visit here: http://php.net/sprintf

I hope this explains enough (it's my first answer) :).

Comment: I have seen the sprintf() used before in things like wordpress, vbulletin, and other well known code.  In your example, $query would then be ran in a regular mysql function?  I realize sprintf() is more secure but I am curious, is this considered a real "prepared statement" or just a similar technique? Thanks

Comment: It won't, however, sanitise your SQL for you. That code won't work. You'll end up with `... AND \`name\` = Simon`—you didn't add the quotes around "Simon", and `sprintf` definitely won't do that for you.

Comment: Yes, you'd then run this through your relevant MySQL query function (mysql_query() if you're using the standard driver). I'm not sure if you would consider sprintf as a real prepared statement but it's close enough at least :-)

@Samir: Apologies, I removed the ' by a mistake. Thanks for pointing it out! +1

Comment: %s won't escape any single-quote within $username, i.e. you can still run into a bobby-tables situation, http://xkcd.com/327/  sprintf() is not a replacement for prepared statements or mysql\_real\_escape\_string(). It can be used in addition to mysql\_real\_escape\_string().

Comment: Oh my god, `sprintf` doesn't protect you AT ALL.  Please update your solution to include `mysql_real_escape_string` on the `%s` parameter.  The `%d` parameter should be OK as-is.

Comment: I wasn't saying use it instead of `mysql_real_escape_string`. I was just showing a way to sort of do easy prepared statements natively using `sprintf`. Of course he should use `mysql_real_escape_string` - I thought that was obvious.

Answer (score 0):

you could try zend_db which uses pdo under the hood. ([mdb2](http://pear.php.net/package/MDB2/redirected) is another option you can use.)

Comment: Zend_Db has adapters for many PDO extensions as well as a few non-PDO extensions, but not MDB2.

Answer (score 0):

PHP lets you do anything you want, and it just so happens PDO does what "you want" with a lot less code. :)